# How to extract fragments of SQL-like query?

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse query having structure:

```
SELECT * FROM /REGION WHERE [where_clauses]
```

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM /TEST WHERE id IN SET ('\'111', '2,22' , ' 333 ', '()', 2) and name='John'
```

I am interested only in where_clauses.

From the example I would expect to find the following:

1) IN SET ('\'111', '2,22' , ' 333 ', '()', 2)

2) name='John'

In addition to that I would like to know the number of elements for "IN SET" and positions of the found values in the original string.

How can I parse this?

Comment: It would certainly be helpful to know more about the problem you are trying to solve. Also what have you tried so far? Have you looked at existing SQL parsers (e.g. H2's)? If those don't work for you, would an ANTLR or JavaCC grammar be usable?

Comment: This is not actualy SQL. Currently I'm looking on Antlr. Thank you about mentioning JavaCC. I'll check what is this.